# zip: set minimum deflate percentage

Tags: compression, zip

I want to create a zip file that will be decompressed by a low-power cpu

Deflate compression decreases the filesize, but adds to the decompression time.

The zip command seems to do some analysis itself on whether or not compression is worth it. Note that for some files, `store` (no-compression) is used, while for others, `deflate` (compression) is used.

When I analyse the output, I see that about 25% of files are compressed with < 10% compression. Assuming this lightly compressed file takes a lot of cpu time to decompress, this is not worth it for me.

Can I tell `zip` to only use `deflate` for files that it can compress by at least 20%?

I'm using the `zip` command bundled with Mac. Would be willing to install additional free software if needed.

```
$ zip -v
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.
$  zip -FSr GravityExpress.pdx.zip ./GravityExpress.pd

  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/music/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/music/StrangeStuff.mp3 (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/music/Escape_Gravity_Express.mp3 (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/music/SmoothAndCool.mp3 (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/music/scifiNights.mp3 (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/music/HomeStretch.mp3 (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/music/UpBeat.mp3 (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/music/AUTO.mp3 (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/music/the-countdown.mp3 (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/card.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/wrapping-pattern.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImage.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/card-pressed.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImages/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImages/9.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImages/8.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImages/10.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImages/5.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImages/4.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImages/6.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImages/7.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImages/3.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImages/2.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/SystemAssets/launchImages/1.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_impact_imminent_2.json (deflated 15%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/congratulations.mp3 (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_other_way_2.mp3 (deflated 3%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_intro_2.mp3 (deflated 3%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_t_minus_ten.pdv (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/orientation.pdv (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_airlock_clear_2.pdv (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_open_airlock_3.mp3 (deflated 3%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_airlock_clear_2.json (deflated 37%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_open_airlock_3.json (deflated 47%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_impact_imminent_2.mp3 (deflated 3%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_intro_2.pdv (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_other_way_2.pdv (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/congratulations.pdv (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_impact_imminent_2.pdv (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_open_airlock_3.pdv (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_airlock_clear_2.mp3 (deflated 3%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/orientation.mp3 (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_t_minus_ten.mp3 (deflated 4%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_intro_2.json (deflated 47%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_t_minus_ten.json (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/congratulations.json (deflated 45%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/director_other_way_2.json (deflated 15%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/video/orientation.json (deflated 52%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/main.pdz (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/sprite_playdate.pdi (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/credits-qr.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/launch_control_crank.pdt (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/card_info_icon.pdi (deflated 7%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/checkpoint_banner.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/rocket_ship_burn_start.pdt (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/start_background.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/launch_control_button.pdt (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/logo.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/level_thumbs.pdt (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/rocket_ship_burn.pdt (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/asteroid_surface.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/rocket_ship.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/sprite_classic.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/launch_tower.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/bricks_playdate.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/launch_control_room.pdi (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/tooltips/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/tooltips/tooltips.pdt (deflated 5%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/launch_control_battery_monitor.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/bricks_classic.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/level-select/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/level-select/connector.pdi (deflated 6%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/level-select/a_button.pdt (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/level-select/d_pad.pdt (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/level-select/console.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/level-select/challenge_bg.pdi (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/images/level-select/large_challenge_icons.pdt (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/settings/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/settings/SettingsViewModel.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/settings/SettingsScreen.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/settings/Options.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/gameView.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/bricksView.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/input/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/gameViewModel.pdz (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/gameInputs.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/start/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/start/startView.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/start/startScreen.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/start/startViewModel.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/game-explosion/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/game-explosion/GameExplosion.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/game-explosion/GameExplosionScreen.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/CamController.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/drawUtil.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/unittests.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/specialsViewModel.pdz (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/common/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/common/PlanePhysicsViewModel.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/common/tooltip.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/gameScreen.pdz (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/game-over/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/game-over/GameOverView.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/game-over/GameOverScreen.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/game-over/GameOverViewModel.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/gameHUD.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/video-player/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/video-player/VideoPlayerView.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/video-player/VideoTimebase.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/video-player/VideoPlayerScreen.pdz (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/video-player/VideoViewModel.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/video-player/VideoPlayerViewModel.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/credits/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/credits/CreditsScreen.pdz (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/credits/Credits.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/credits/CreditsViewModel.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/credits/CreditsView.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/end-game/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/end-game/EndGameViewModel.pdz (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/end-game/FlyToCreditsView.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/end-game/FlyToCreditsScreen.pdz (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/end-game/EndGameView.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/end-game/FlyToCreditsViewModel.pdz (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/end-game/EndGameScreen.pdz (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/specialsView.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/level-select/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/level-select/levelSelectView.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/level-select/levelSelectScreen.pdz (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/level-select/lockAnimation.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/lua/level-select/levelSelectViewModel.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/libs/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/pickup.pda (deflated 17%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/thrust.pda (deflated 11%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/rocket_engine_loop.pda (deflated 81%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/barrier.pda (deflated 26%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/unlock_denied.pda (deflated 26%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/conveyor_belt.pda (deflated 11%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/key.pda (deflated 17%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/dump.pda (deflated 11%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/hollow-swish-airy-short.pda (deflated 11%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/extra_cargo.pda (deflated 8%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/classic/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/classic/pickup.pda (deflated 18%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/classic/key.pda (deflated 17%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/classic/dump.pda (deflated 21%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/classic/extra.pda (deflated 12%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/classic/fuel.pda (deflated 10%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/fuel.pda (deflated 11%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/electronic_hum.pda (deflated 52%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/hollow-swish-airy-short-reverse.pda (deflated 17%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/blower.pda (deflated 11%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/extra_turbo.pda (deflated 8%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/landing.pda (deflated 22%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/ui_cancel.pda (deflated 31%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/launch_control_click.pda (deflated 85%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/rocket_engine_stop.pda (deflated 12%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/unlock.pda (deflated 10%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/ui_confirm.pda (deflated 31%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/extra_life.pda (deflated 10%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/rocket_engine_start.pda (deflated 12%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/sounds/explosion.pda (deflated 18%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/pdxinfo (deflated 22%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL22.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL23.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL09.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL21.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL20.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL08.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL24.pdz (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL18.pdz (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL19.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL25.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL20.bin (deflated 65%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL08.bin (deflated 60%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL01.pdv (deflated 9%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL15.pdv (deflated 6%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL14.pdv (deflated 6%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL09.bin (deflated 61%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL21.bin (deflated 60%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL23.bin (deflated 72%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL16.pdv (deflated 17%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL02.pdv (deflated 4%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL03.pdv (deflated 11%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL17.pdv (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL22.bin (deflated 63%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL13.pdv (deflated 4%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL07.pdv (deflated 36%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL06.pdv (deflated 38%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL12.pdv (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL19.bin (deflated 64%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL25.bin (deflated 61%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL04.pdv (deflated 19%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL10.pdv (deflated 4%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL11.pdv (deflated 9%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL05.pdv (deflated 22%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL24.bin (deflated 66%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL18.bin (deflated 62%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/CREDITS.bin (deflated 56%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/README.md (deflated 21%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL15.bin (deflated 55%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL01.bin (deflated 62%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL20.pdv (deflated 8%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL08.pdv (deflated 4%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL09.pdv (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL21.pdv (deflated 5%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL14.bin (deflated 64%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL02.bin (deflated 63%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL16.bin (deflated 61%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL23.pdv (deflated 18%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL22.pdv (deflated 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL17.bin (deflated 62%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL03.bin (deflated 66%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL07.bin (deflated 59%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL13.bin (deflated 59%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL12.bin (deflated 65%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL06.bin (deflated 87%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL10.bin (deflated 88%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL04.bin (deflated 68%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL19.pdv (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL25.pdv (deflated 4%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL24.pdv (deflated 1%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL18.pdv (deflated 3%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL05.bin (deflated 62%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL11.bin (deflated 61%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL17.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL03.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL02.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL16.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL14.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/CREDITS.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL15.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL01.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL05.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL11.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL10.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL04.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL12.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL06.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL07.pdz (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/levels/LEVEL13.pdz (deflated 2%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/fonts/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/fonts/digital-7-mono-20.pft (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/fonts/Edit Undo/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/fonts/Edit Undo/edit-undo.dot-brk-50.pft (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/fonts/Roobert/ (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/fonts/Roobert/Roobert-10-Bold.pft (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/fonts/Roobert/Roobert-9-Mono-Condensed.pft (stored 0%)
  adding: GravityExpress.pdx/fonts/abduction2002bold-20.pft (stored 0%)
```

Comment: Free 7Zip has a good interface for its many speed settings: https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-make-7-zip-faster/ and can be installed on Mac: https://ports.macports.org/port/7zip/ (It also works well in wine on Linux). It's worth a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip), "zip automatically chooses the better of the two (deflation or store...) for each file to be compressed."

One can guide the behavior using -n to exclude certain file suffixes from compression.  In your example, adding -n .mp3:.json:.pdz would get you close.  You can update your ZIPOPT environment variable to do this automatically.

There is also a -# switch that regulates compression speed.  -0 indicates no compression, -1 indicates the fastest (and least) compression.  -9 is the slowest and ignores the suffix list. The default is -6.

ZIP is [open source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/), so with significantly more effort, you can add your own behaviors.

Comment: With the -1 option, mp3's were still compressed, but the -n .mp3 worked well, thanks!